# Show navbar when move / touch up

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

On a mobile website is a navbar on top. The navbar position is made with position:absolute:

```
.navbar-fixed-top{position:absolute;right:0;left:0;z-index:1000;
```

When move down the navbar should be invisible and when move up the navbar should be visible again. There are alot of examples on the web how to do his with scroll for desktop such as this:

http://jsfiddle.net/mariusc23/s6mLJ/31/

http://codepen.io/sunnyxyst/pen/DwgFm

[Jquery sticky nav only when scrolling up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15906309/jquery-sticky-nav-only-when-scrolling-up)

This examples dont work on a mobile device.

Thank you for help. I cant use Bootstrap.

Comment: is this all the css you have? can you pst the html

Answer (score 0):

its working with

jsfiddle.net/mariusc23/s6mLJ/31/

Important is to have a smartphone with android > 2, because we need    position:fixed